# How to extract a pattern and embed it into span elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i am new to programming. i want to extract a string and embed it into span element how can i do it?

consider i have string

"i am [12@some user] some text [2@some user2]"

i want to identity strings in square brackets and extract the values after @ so

"some user" and "some user2" should be extracted and form a string like below,

"i am `<span>some user</span>` some text `<span>some user2</span>`"

how do i do it using the algorithm below

```
const final_string = []
const original_string = "i am [12@some user] some text [2@some user2]"
let prev_match_pos = 0
for each match in original_string
    final_string.push(text from the end of prev match up until current 
    match start)
    final_string.push(<span>match</span>)
update prev_match_pos

final_string.push(text from the end of previous match to the end of the 
original string)
```

i am using this pattern to match /[\d+@(?[^]\r\n]*)]/g

```
const matches = original_string.matchAll(/\[\d+@(?<name>[^\]\r\n]*)]/g);
let matches_another = [];
for (const match of matches) {
    matches_another.push(match.groups.name);
}
```

Now how do i get to do the other part of the algorithm. i get the matches in matches_another array.

now how to proceed further. could someone help me with this thanks.

Comment: "extract the values after £"  ?

Comment: sorry typo its after @ character will edit

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the two words like:

```
let str = "i am [12@some user] some text [2@some user2]";

let reg = /\[\w*@/;
let user1 = str.split(reg)[1].split(']')[0];
let user2 = str.split(reg)[2].slice(0,-1);
console.log('user1= ' + user1 +' & user2= '+ user2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the matches, [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex will work:

```js
const original_string = "i am [12@some user] some text [2@some user2]";
const final_string = original_string.replace(/\[\d+@([^\]\r\n]*)]/g, '<span>$1</span>');
console.log(final_string);
```

(I've removed the named group from the regex because it's not supported everywhere and it's not necessary here.)